# ClickOnce deployment & settings file

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have a problem with a clickonce deployed application.
When I try to read somethink from the settings file, application crash.

The line of the code in my project is:

```
CurrentLogin = Properties.Settings.Default.LastLogin;
```

The error is:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1026
Date:       16.02.2011
Time:       14:02:35
User:       N/A
Computer:   W-MD-IS-6393
Description:
Application: BlaBlaBla.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at BlaBlaBla.App.InitializeComponent()
   at BlaBlaBla.App.Main()
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ClickOnce cache and find the folder with your executable in it. Double-click on the executable -- does the application run successfully, or does it have the same error? If it has the same error, then it is a bug in your application, not a ClickOnce problem.

On a Windows 7 or Vista machine, the cache is here:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\

Then you will see a bunch of folders. Assuming your app is not a VSTO add-in, look for a folder with the first four letters of your assembly name, and then "tion" (not "exe). For example, if your assembly name is Silverlight, look for a folder that looks like this -- "silv...tion...".

THat should be the folder with your executable in it.